# How can I set the default time format for dmesg?

Tags: ubuntu, dmesg

I use dmesg in Ubuntu heavily. I like the iso time format but I hate typing it out every time, so I use something like this in my .bashrc to set the default time format for dmesg:

```
# Setup alias for dmesg
alias dmesg="/bin/dmesg --time-format=iso"
```

Is there a better/proper way of doing this? Per user or globally, I don't care.

Comment: Better than what you have already? Which works perfectly?

Comment: It works fine, I'm just trying to find out if it reads a profile file somewhere else that I should be editing instead.

Comment: It sure looks like you edited the correct file. What more do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dmesg doesn't have a configuration file, so the only way to change its behavior is via command line options. As such, the way you're doing this is just fine.